# Limit of the ratio of series of non negative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_{n,p}\}_{n,p \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_{n,p}\}_{n,p \in \mathbb{N}}$ be two double sequences of non negative real numbers.

We know that:
$$
\forall p \in \mathbb{N}:
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,p}<\infty,
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n,p}<\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}
\dfrac
{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,p}}
{\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n,p}}
=0
$$
and exists
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}
\dfrac{a_{n,p}}{b_{n,p}}
$$
My question is if it is true that:
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}
\dfrac{a_{n,p}}{b_{n,p}}
=0
$$

Comment: What have your tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. For all $p$, let $b_{p,p}=p$ and otherwise $a_{n,p}=b_{n,p}=1/n^2$. The tails are the same so clearly for each fixed $n$,
$$
\lim_{p\to \infty} \frac{a_{n,p}}{b_{n,p}}=1.
$$
For each fixed $p$, both sequences have summable tails so have finite sums. But 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n,p}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2=C, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n,p}>b_{p,p}=p,
$$
where $C$ is a constant, and so
$$
0\leq \lim_{p\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n,p}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n,p}}\leq \lim_{p\to \infty} \frac{C}{p}=0.
$$

Comment: thanks @JasonGaitonde for your answer